# Window function that can do a percentage calculation better than 2 CTE's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to calculate the percentage of an article at a size level of the whole by first getting the total quantity at the size level in one CTE and then creating another CTE to get the total quantity just at article level. In the code below that seems to work but it also quite long and takes while to run.

I am curious if there is a more efficient way, possibly using `OVER` or possibly another window function to get the same result.  I have used `OVER` before but since these are at different levels of granularity I am not quite sure.

SQL:

```
WITH      SumByMaterialCTE (MATERIAL, QUANTITY) --used to get the sum of quantity of an article for all demand 

AS    (SELECT MATERIAL, SUM(QUANTITY) 
                             FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION_COMBINED
                             WHERE REQUIREMENT_TYPE <> ''
                             GROUP BY MATERIAL), 

       DemandSizeLevelCTE (MATERIAL, SIZE_LITERAL, SIZE_PERCENT) --used to get a percentage for each size of an article over the total demand

AS     (SELECT DS.MATERIAL, 
               DS.SIZE_LITERAL,
               (SUM(DS.QUANTITY)/SM.QUANTITY) AS 'SIZE_PERCENT'
        FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION_COMBINED DS
        JOIN SumByMaterialCTE SM ON DS.MATERIAL = SM.MATERIAL
        WHERE DS.REQUIREMENT_TYPE <> '' 
        GROUP BY DS.MATERIAL, DS.SIZE_LITERAL, SM.QUANTITY)


SELECT DS.MATERIAL, 
       DS.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       DS.SIZE_PERCENT 

FROM   DemandSizeLevelCTE DS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions, summing over Material and Size and dividing by a sum over material to get the percentages of each size for each material:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL, SIZE_LITERAL,
       SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, SIZE_LITERAL) AS TOTAL_SIZE,
       SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL) AS TOTAL_MATERIAL,
       100.0 * SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL, SIZE_LITERAL) /
       SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL) AS SIZE_PERCENT
FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION_COMBINED
ORDER BY MATERIAL, SIZE_LITERAL
```

I've created a sample [demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/727de2/3) for which the output is:

```
MATERIAL    SIZE_LITERAL    TOTAL_SIZE  TOTAL_MATERIAL  SIZE_PERCENT
COTTON      L               3           22              13.636363636363
COTTON      M               11          22              50
COTTON      S               8           22              36.363636363636
NYLON       L               10          19              52.631578947368
NYLON       M               2           19              10.526315789473
NYLON       S               4           19              21.052631578947
NYLON       XL              3           19              15.78947368421
```

Comment: one thing I was a bit curious on - I noticed you had to use the DISTINCT operator in that version (which works perfect), with the two CTE's I didn't need to and I am trying to understand why

Comment: @XCCH004 because there is no `GROUP BY` in the query, it will return a row for every instance of say `COTTON` and `S`, which would all be duplicates. Using `DISTINCT` gets rid of them. Try removing the `DISTINCT` from my demo and you'll see what I mean. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/727de2/4